# Avraham a father of many

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham

What was meant when HaShem told Avraham His covenant would be with him and he would become the father of a multitude of nations? (Genesis 17:4, see also 12:2-3).

To whom does the multitude of nations refer?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Yisrael, Avraham's descendants include:

- Yishmael (Arabs)
- Eisav (Edom, Amalek)
- six children of Keturah, who might each count as their own nation (but I have no source for that)